# intro to python - series of numbers

Tags: python

I have been going through an introduction to python booklet and have been stuck on the following question. the question is outlined below and my attempt follows after the question.

> Take this program:
>
> ```
>  m = 0
> finished = False
> while not finished:
>   print('Enter another whole number (0 to finish): ', end = '')
>   s = input()
>   num = int(s)
>   if num != 0:
>       if num > m:
>           m = num
>   else:
>       finished = True
> print(str(m))
> ```
>
> If you have worked out what the above program does, can you see that,
>   for certain series
>
> of numbers, it will not produce the correct output? In what
>   circumstances will it not
>
> work correctly, and how could you change
>   the program to make it work properly?

My understanding is that the series of numbers, where the above program will fail, are decimal numbers (non-whole number), therefore my attempt is as follows:

```
m='0'
finished = False
while not finished:
    print('enter number, 0 to finish: ', end = '')
    num = input()
    if num != '0':
        if num > m:
            m = num
    else:
        finished = True
print(m)
```

However this fails at understanding that 77 is larger than 8 since it is reading it as a string.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the "correct output" would even be, and the purpose of `m` (or the entire program for that matter.

Comment: decimal numbers are also called `floating point` numbers, to implement that just change `num = int(s)` to `num = float(s)` in the original code

Comment: This is opinion based since you haven't sufficiently described your requirements. Based on what you've given, I'd assume the way you deal with this issue is by ensuring whole numbers are entered rather than accepting floats; that would change the prompt/program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program calculates the maximum value from the inputted sequence. It stores the maximal value in `m`, and if a `num` is inputted that's larger than it, it keeps it as the new maximum.

However, note that `m` is initialized with `0`, making the implicit assumption that at least one number you'll input is positive. If you input only negative numbers, you'll get `0` as the largest number, which is clearly wrong, as you never inputted it.

A quick fix could be to initialize `m` with `None` and explicitly check for it:

```
m = None
finished = False
while not finished:
  print('Enter another whole number (0 to finish): ', end = '')
  s = input()
  num = int(s)
  if num != 0:
      if not m or num > m:
          m = num
  else:
      finished = True
print(str(m))
```